# In Pathfinder, what is a good class for a player who will miss sessions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, problem-players, class

I am playing in a Pathfinder campaign but because of scheduling I know I will miss at least one out of every four sessions.

What is a class whose absence will impact the group little and at the same time provide a logical in game reason for the character being absent?

The reason I ask is because the DM does not like having others decide the characters actions in order to avoid the whole "you got my character killed" or "my character would have never done that" scenario.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how we work. How many players are there? Do you know what classes other players are planning on taking? Will you lose the XP for the sessions you miss (And therefore fall behind in levels)? What materials are allowed? There's a whole lot of details required to make this narrow enough to be answered.

Comment: Are you looking for in-character explanations for why your character isn't there half the time, or mechanical classes that work with the party without being missed if they're not there?

Comment: Asides from the obvious "Don't pick a role that is vital for your party to succeed", what kind of advice are you hoping to get here? Fluff-wise the absence of a character is easy to handwave regardless of their class.

Comment: Consider that class probably doesn't matter, you may want to ask about your actual problem (How do I make it easy on my GM if I'm going to miss a lot of sessions) as opposed to focusing on class.